# Is there any logic to dereferencing a variable for use within a lambda to allow garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection

I have a memory-heavy object (foo) and a smaller object (bar) held within. I want to make sure foo is garbage collected but need access to the `hello` field within my lambda for the lifetime of the program.

I am wondering if there is any logic to first dereferencing bar into its own variable before creating my lambda. I believe that this may allow foo to be garbage collected but am not certain.

I.e. in the following example, as I am only using `bar.hello`, is there any logic in doing `B` over `A` to allow `foo` to be garbage collected? Does the first lambda (A) implicitly hold a reference to foo, and does the second (B) remove this reference?

```java
    class Bar { // Use within lambda
        String hello;
    }
    
    class Foo { // Memory-heavy class
        Bar bar;
        String world;
    }
    
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    
    // A (access bar through foo, will foo remain in memory?)
    run(() -> System.out.println(foo.bar.hello));
    
    // B (foo should have no more references, should be GC'd?)
    Bar bar = foo.bar;
    run(() -> System.out.println(bar.hello));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Properly speaking, `foo` is a variable, which references a class `Foo` instance.

But yes, changing the lambda expression will enable garbage collection of the class `Foo` instance.

```
public class LambdaTest {

public static class OuterClass {
    public InnerClass inner;
}

public static class InnerClass {
    public String value;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Attempting to define the value printer lambda here fails,
    // since 'outer1' is neither final nor effectively final.
    //
    // Requiring 'outer1' to be final enables safe inlining of
    // outer's value.  Otherwise, a reference to stack frame
    // would be held by the lambda.  Languages which place stack frames
    // on the heap don't do this.  java is not one of those language.

    // OuterClass outer1 = null;
    //
    // Runnable valuePrinter =
    //     () -> { System.out.println("Value [ " + outer.inner.value + " ]"); };
    // outer1 = new OuterClass();

    OuterClass outer1 = new OuterClass();       

    // The value of 'outer1' is inlined in the lambda.
    //
    // This creates a new reference to the value of 'outer1', which will prevent
    // that OuterClass instance from being garbage collected.

    Runnable valuePrinter1 =
        () -> { System.out.println("Inside lambda1 [ " + outer1.inner.value + " ]"); };

    // A new assignment to 'outer1' would cause the lambda definition to
    // fail.

    // outer = new OuterClass();

    outer1.inner = new InnerClass();
    outer1.inner.value = "TestValue1";
    System.out.println("Outside lambda1 [ " + outer1.inner.value + " ]");
    valuePrinter1.run();

    // While the 'outer1' value was inlined, the other parts of the
    // 'outer.inner.value' expression were not.
    //
    // Changes made to the 'value' and 'inner' references are visible to
    // the lambda.

    outer1.inner.value = "TestValue2";
    System.out.println("Outside lambda1 [ " + outer1.inner.value + " ]");
    valuePrinter1.run();
    
    outer1.inner = new InnerClass();
    outer1.inner.value = "TestValue3";
    System.out.println("Outside lambda1 [ " + outer1.inner.value + " ]");
    valuePrinter1.run();
    
    OuterClass outer2 = new OuterClass();               
    InnerClass inner2 = new InnerClass();
    outer2.inner = inner2;
    inner2.value = "TestValue4";

    // The InnerClass instance referenced by 'inner2' has no reference to
    // the OuterClass instance referenced by 'outer2'.
    //
    // The lambda 'valuePrinter2' inlines the reference held by 'inner2'.
    //
    // A live reference to 'valuePrinter2' will not prevent the value referenced
    // by 'outer2' from being garbage collected.

    System.out.println("Outside lambda2 [ " + inner2.value + " ]");
    Runnable valuePrinter2 =
        () -> { System.out.println("Inside lambda2 [ " + inner2.value + " ]"); };
    valuePrinter2.run();
}

// Output:
//
// Outside lambda1 [ TestValue1 ]
// Inside lambda1 [ TestValue1 ]
// Outside lambda1 [ TestValue2 ]
// Inside lambda1 [ TestValue2 ]
// Outside lambda1 [ TestValue3 ]
// Inside lambda1 [ TestValue3 ]
// Outside lambda2 [ TestValue4 ]
// Inside lambda2 [ TestValue4 ]
```

}

Answer (score 0):

That is one interesting question, imho.

Here is how I've simplified the code base a bit:

```
public class DeleteMe {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Foo foo = new Foo();

        Thread t = new Thread(() -> System.out.println(foo.bar.hello));
        t.start();

    }

    static class Bar { // Use within lambda
        String hello = "hello";
    }

    static class Foo { // Memory-heavy class
        Bar bar = new Bar();
    }
}
```

Now this is a capturing lambda and if you run it (with a special flag: `-Djdk.internal.lambda.dumpProxyClasses=/some/path/goes/here`) and look at the de-compiled code, you will notice that it "captures" a `Foo` *instance*. In somehow simpler words, that lambda will be transformed into a class (that implements `Runnable`) internally that will take a `Foo` instance as an argument.

If you change that code to:

```
Foo foo = new Foo();
Bar bar = foo.bar;

Thread t = new Thread(() -> System.out.println(bar.hello));
t.start();
```

Run that with the same flag, decompile - you will see that a `Bar` instance is now captured.

This changes things.

---

This means that `Foo` instance is eligible for GC, as soon as this line is hit:

```
run(() -> System.out.println(bar.hello));
```

And this is exactly what you wanted.

The other code that has :

```
Thread t = new Thread(() -> System.out.println(foo.bar.hello));
```

as I said, will be transformed to a `class` that implements `Runnable` and will sort of look like this:

```
class RunnableImpl implements Runnable {
     private final Foo foo;

     public RunnableImpl(Foo foo) {
         this.foo = foo;
     }

     public void run(){
         Bar bar = foo.bar;
         System.out.println(bar.hello);
     }
}
```

It is not exactly like this, but it does not matter (for this example) if I translate it *entirely* correct. This means that the `Thread` instance, will have a `Runnable` instance stored inside it (an instance of `RunnableImpl`), which in turn as seen above will have an instance of `Foo`.

So in the second variant, `foo` can only be collected when the Thread ends; which potentially can be a lot later in time, then before the thread even starts.

Comment: Very interesting, thank you for the detailed answer.

Comment: Without knowing what the OP’s `run` method does, this is a far-fetched conclusion. The variant that extracts `bar` before entering the `run` method, allows collecting the `Foo` instance even before the `run` method is entered. In the other variant, the lifetime of the `Foo` instance depends on the lifetime of the generated `Runnable `. Even in your example, the `Thread` instance holds a reference to the `RunnableImpl` in a field, which has a reference to the `Foo` instance in a field, so it won’t be collected before the thread terminated. Much later than “even before the thread started”.

Comment: @Holger hmm, but why `foo` instance can't be collected at this point `System.out.println(bar.hello);` in the `run` method? What is prohibiting GC to do that?

Comment: The *field* `foo` in the `RunnableImpl` instance.

Comment: Upon further tests, I believe that this answer is incorrect as the proxy class holds a reference to the large object thus it is still kept in memory. Looks like B does allow the object to be collected after all.

Comment: @Holger damn I am an idiot, _of course_ you are right.

Comment: @TimCura yes, I feel terrible sorry for this answer, it makes a false promise. I will edit in shortly. I still can't believe I made such a foolish mistake